# Dynamic Sql - retrieve from Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a form with button which should find records from Oracle database. I have three Textboxes on same form, and If text matches with values in fields of DB, Datagrid should show me this records. Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'connect to oracle DB
      Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=orcl;User Id=Lucky;Password=Example;"
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
        conn.Open()

        Dim SQL As String

        SQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 1=1"

        'SQL statement for 1st textbox
        If Not TxtName.Text = "" Then
            SQL = SQL & " AND USER_NAME =" & TxtName.Text
        End If

        'SQL statement for 2nd textbox
        If Not TxtSurname.Text = "" Then
            SQL = SQL & " AND USER_SURNAME ="  & TxtSurname.Text
        End If

        'SQL statement for 3rd textbox
        If Not TxtAddress.Text = "" Then
            SQL = SQL & " AND USER_ADDRESS=" & TxtAddress.Text
        End If

        'select SQL statements and retrieve data using ExecuteReader
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(SQL, conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(dr)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong, nothing happens when button clicked?

Comment: You should be using parameters for your input values. Also remove that 'where 1=1', it doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Hi andrew. What parameters, I'm VB.NET newbie? "Where 1=1" serves in Access and some DB, I thought here too, will remove it.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 he means, don't concatenate your value to your query. Someone could put a special character in the textbox and screw up your database.

Comment: Ok, but why then andrew just showed how to concatenate?

Comment: I showed building the sql statement using concatenation, which is fine. It isn't adding user input text values in the concatenation, which @the_lotus is correctly saying is wrong, and dangerous. Read here for more info https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-tested sample of the direction you could try:

```vb
Private Sub populateDataGridView()

        'connect to oracle DB
        Const connectionString As String = "Data Source=orcl;User Id=Lucky;Password=Example;"

        Using conn As New OracleConnection(connectionString)

            conn.Open()

            Using cmd As New OracleCommand()

                Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM testtable "
                Dim conjunction As String = " Where "
                'SQL statement for 1st textbox
                If Not TxtName.Text.Length = 0 Then
                    SQL = String.Concat(SQL, conjunction, " USER_NAME like :username")
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("username", String.Concat("%", TxtName.Text, "%")))
                    conjunction = " and "
                End If

                'SQL statement for 2nd textbox
                If Not TxtSurname.Text.Length = 0 Then
                    SQL = String.Concat(SQL, conjunction, " user_surname  like :usersurname")
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("usersurname", String.Concat("%", TxtSurname2.Text, "%")))
                    conjunction = " and "
                End If

                'SQL statement for 3rd textbox
                If Not TxtAddress.Text.Length = 0 Then
                    SQL = String.Concat(SQL, conjunction, " user_address like :useraddress")
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("useraddress", String.Concat("%", TxtAddress.Text, "%")))
                End If

                'select SQL statements and retrieve data using ExecuteReader
                cmd.Connection = conn
                cmd.CommandText = SQL
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(dr)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Andrew, ok now I see what you were thinking. Though still nothing happens, same as before - when I click button, just another empty datagrid is painted. Datagrid is inside split container, I only added It and created columns - must I do anything else with datagrid ?

Comment: Does the ExecuteReader succeed? I.e. do you have rows in the result? You don't need to create columns as it should inherit the columns from the datatable.

Comment: I removed columns. Now I get rows in result, but empty, as before.

Comment: I've updated it to use wildcards. Tested successfully.

Comment: Andrew and sstan, now It works !! thanks guys !!...Just one thing - allways like this when doing dynamic SQL in VB.NET or any other approaches - maybe some link ?

Comment: Sorry, not working, got excited too fast. Now It allways just show records in datagrid, not excluding records I want to see, by typing criteria in textboxes....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117216/discussion-between-andrew-mortimer-and-luckyluke82).

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Log the query and try it directly in your database until you get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, for all your help !!